# get a char passed as parameter

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention

I would like to write a function in NASM System V ABI x86-64 (Intel Syntax) that I could use in a C program.

Here is the prototype of the function:

```
char *rindex(const char *s, int c);
```

I therefore retrieve the parameters in order (`const char *s` = `rdi`, `int c` = `rsi`)

First, I get the character stored in the register `rsi` and put it in `ah`:

```
segment .text

global rindex:function

rindex:
    mov ah, byte [rsi] ;; get the character
    [...]
```

Unfortunately, this line crashes my program:

```
rindex("hello world", 'o') // segfault
```

Why it is impossible to get the char and what would be the correct way?

Comment: Char is pointed by rdi, not rsi.

Comment: I thought the arguments should be passed in this order : `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`. Is it not the case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call "char" your first argument (`const char *s = rdi`), since it is a pointer to `char`. Your second argument (`int c = rsi`) is an `int`. To access elements of the string pointed by `s` you can use `mov ah, byte ptr [rdi]`. But your second argument is not a pointer, `rsi` contains the value of `c`. To read it you can read from `esi`, since the value of an `int` fits in the lower 32-bits of `rsi`.

Comment: Indeed, the character is stored in `al`, thank you!

Comment: So it's just an int whose value is always between 0 and 256, i.e. the low byte.  You don't have to move it anywhere, you can access it where it is as the 8-bit `sil` register.  For instance, `cmp [rdi], sil` to see if the first byte matches.

Comment: `mov rax, rsi` would copy 64 bits, including possible non-zero garbage above the 32-bit `int` value in ESI.  If you want to zero-extend just the low 8 bits, `movzx eax, sil`  (C functions such as strchr that a `char` as the bottom of an `int`, so that's why the OP is calling it a "char").  Or like Nate said, just use it directly in SIL.

Comment: @Midway @NateEldredge When the second argument is an int whose value is always between 0 and 255, would it not be better to declare it as `char`?

Comment: @PeterCordes The fact that `strchr` and other string functions have character arguments with `int` type always confused me.

Comment: @nevilad: declaring it as `int` forces the caller to zero-extend it to 32 bits, in case that matters.  e.g. makes it easy to broadcast by multiplying with `0x01010101` if you want to use a 4-byte-at-a-time bithack.

Comment: Declaring as `int` I think dates back to the days of ancient C before prototypes, when the only way to call functions was via the default argument promotions (where narrower types promote to int or unsigned), like we have now for variadic functions or declarations that don't specify arg types.  (e.g. `char *strchr();` in C, as opposed to C++ where that means `(void)`.).  For exact compatibility with all possible calling conventions, C chose to make those args be `int`, just like the caller passes with no prototype.